# How to run method with Delayed Job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, delayed-job

I tried to run methods with delayed_job but keep getting error

```
Job failed to load: allocator undefined for Method...
```

Delayed_job stores the task in table but can't run it. Mailer is working just fine with delayed_job. I tried with method_name.delay and handle_asynchronously :method_name but always getting same error.

Comment: Please include a snippet of your code where the problem lies. I can tell from your description that the delay call needs to be `@actor.delay.method_name`, and not the other way around. The more you post, the more we can help you.

Comment: Problem was in serialization and deserialization of method name and parameters. I figured out how to make custom job, it is not most beautiful, but it is a working way.